# Illustrator: pixels lost after fitting to artwork bounds and saving for web

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

1. I am editing an svg file:

[image: No fit]

2. I am using `Object -> Artboards -> Fit to Artwork Bounds` which seem to work well:

[image: Fit]

3. But when I save for web as a small dimension (73x64) png I get this result:

[image: Result]

As you can see, the bike's wheels "flatten" because Illustrator cuts a couple of pixels off the bottom and right corners of the image.

4. To make the image not lose its edges, is there an alternative to enlarging the artboard pixel by pixel and saving each time until the result is statisfying?

Answer (score 1):

Make the artboard one or two pixels larger (on each side), to leave room for the anti-aliasing pixels bleeding over the paths. This also helps with (vector) SVGs where a tight bounding box can cut into the smoothing pixels.

Comment: It does work, but I wanted to avoid this bit-tedious process. I have to increase the artboard by 1px at a time on each side because in addition to not wanting to lose the edges, I want to to not have white space around. (The image will be displayed as a small icon so white space doesn't serve me well). But maybe this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Skip step 2 and go straight to Save for web and in that dialog box, **uncheck** the 'Clip to artboard' option. I downloaded your AI file and generated this in 4 seconds using this method. My AI doesn't seem to cut off the wheels like your AI does.

[image]

If that doesn't work, put a no-fill, no-stroke rectangle around the artwork and again Save for web with 'Clip to artboard' unchecked.

[image]

Comment: Weirdly, now I don't lose pixels on the right; but I still lose pixels at the bottom.

Comment: There may be a problem with the SVG file, many times SVG's can cause AI to act weird. Go into outline mode CTRL+Y and see if there's any clipping mask in there (any square box surrounding the artwork).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but no... https://imgur.com/a/MwRC1Ou

Comment: Select the whole shabang, paste it in Photoshop and try to save for web from there? :)

Comment: Will have to download Photoshop and try. I will post an update. Thank you, would've upvoted if I could ;)

Comment: Yeah. Most likely something wrong with the file, AI will not behave like this with 'clean' artwork. Upload the SVG and i'll look at this for you.

Comment: Thank you! https://ufile.io/u5jd56kq https://ufile.io/sggqguoh . BTW, Maybe it has something to do with the image being originally png. I used "Image Trace > Low Fidelity Photo" from there to convert to svg (so I can edit it easily).

Comment: @Django - after you trace the image, try hitting the Expand button, then rescale the artboard to fit. Now try your export.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks, but the result stays the same

Comment: @Lucian Did you try saving the image in small dimensions (64px height)? That's when the trouble begins. Ugh, a no-fill rectangle has no effect (it just ignores it when saving w/ "Clip to artboard" unticked). Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: @Lucian You enlightened me about the "clip to artboard" untick so it did help in general :)